# AWS Amplify Express API - Typescript?

Tags: typescript, express, aws-lambda, aws-amplify

I'm unfortunately struggling to figure out how I can properly set up my amplify api(s) to be in TypesScript, and then transpile to JavaScript.

This may sound silly to ask, as it should be a relatively simple transpile process, but if anyone could guide me through this process, I'd be very grateful.

I haven't moved past the boilerplate express js generated code through the Amplify CLI for adding an API, and need to get past this barrier to begin actual development for my controllers.

I've followed [Amplify Function Build Options](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/function/build-options/) to a T - albeit the discrepancies between a vanilla lambda function and an express js one.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Building an API using typescript in Amplify is pretty rough. The best way i found is creating a separate folder to store your project and then set that project to transpile into the Amplify API folder (you should copy the dependencies that you install into the package.json in the API folder).